# How to optimize the join performance in Hive while using multiple large tables

Tags: sql, hive

We are using multiple large tables and small tables in Hive. We need to perform multiple `INNER JOIN`s but my join's execution was not getting completed even after 3 hours. I have used one technique where we need to use large tables in the end.
My sample code is like below:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.name,
    a.qual,
    a.year
FROM emp 1 a
    INNER JOIN emp2 b
        ON trim(a.qual) = (b.qual)
    INNER JOIN emp3 c
        ON trim(a.qual) = (c.qual)
    INNER JOIN emp4 d
        ON trim(c.year) = (d.year)
    INNER JOIN emp5 e
        ON trim(a.qual) = (e.qual)
AND trim(d.marks) = (e.marks)
GROUP BY 
    a.name,
    a.qual,
    a.year;

emp1 = count 5677
emp2 = count 7890900
emp3 = count 8755788
emp4 = count 78524565
emp5 = count 875684265
```

Above tables have schema of name, age, month, qual, year.
These are not actual tables. Just to give the logic, I have renamed table names and column names. My real logic and table counts was pretty much the same.

Comment: IMO, Bucketing and partitioning should help in improving the query performance.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on any table?

Comment: We don't have any indexes and What is IMO?

Comment: Start by removing the `trim()` and fixing the data.  Functions for join conditions are just likely to impede the optimizer.  Then, you might inquire how many rows the query is supposed to return.

Comment: 3 hours of elapsed time is not that bad for a batch process. This is for a batch process, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering any rows from the primary table `emp1`. In this case a full table scan is the best solution for this table. It has 5k rows so it's not a problem by any length.

However, on the related tables you may want to use indexes when accessing them. I would try:

```
create index ix1 on emp5 (qual);

create index ix2 on emp4 (year);

create index ix3 on emp3 (qual);

create index ix4 on emp2 (qual);
```

These indexes should improve the join performance quite a bit, but it will still depend on how many rows are you actually selecting from each table.

If this doesn't help, then you'll need to retrieve the execution plan of the query. If you post it, then we can help you reading it.

Also, it's always a good idea to fix the data model, clean the data, and remove the `trim()` functions you are using. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to be critical for this query, since Nested Loop Joins (NLJ) should work efficiently in this case anyway.

Good luck.